# Query many Date formats from parse into Array Swift

Tags: arrays, swift, date, parse-platform, nsdate

I am trying to retrieve Objects from parse and take the "createdAt" and append to an Array to put it in a tableview i got this so far:
(the lines with //// is the lines that not working)

```
    var date = [String]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
 messageTextfield.sizeToFit()
    var query = PFQuery(className:"messages")
    query.whereKey("receivers", equalTo:(user?.username)!)
    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
        (objects: [PFObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

        if error == nil {
            print("Successfully retrieved \(objects!.count) messages.")

                for object in objects! {
                     self.messagesSender.append(object["sender"] as! (String))
                    self.messagesID.append(object.objectId!)
                    self.messageMessage.append(object["message"] as! (String))
                 /////var messageCreated = object["createdAt"]
                 /////let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
                 /////dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MMM,dd-YYYY-hh"
                 /////self.date.append(dateFormatter.stringFromDate(messageCreated as! NSDate))
                    print(self.messagesID)
                    print(self.messagesSender)
                    print(self.messageMessage)
                    self.reloadTableView()
                }

        } else {
            // Log details of the failure
            print("Error: \(error!) \(error!.userInfo)")
        }
    }
```

the error occurs at line    "/////self.date.append(dateFormatter.stringFromDate(messageCreated as! NSDate))"    and it says "unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value."

Comment: Try this    `self.date.append(dateFormatter.stringFromDate(messageCreated as! NSDate) as! String)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ahh! I'v run into this before! **createdAt** is a build in method with Parse for swift. Replace `var messageCreated = object["createdAt"]` with `var messageCreated = object.createdAt!` and you'll be good to go!